# How do I remove my old apk and publish an update on the Google play market?

Tags: google-play

How do I remove my old APK and publish an update on the Google play market?  I have a published APK but I put something extra in my code.  I have figured out how to un-publish my app, but how do I delete the old and upload new?I try to Deactivate and upload new...and send me a msg The new apk's versionCode (1) already exists....but i have modified the code and make new signed...if change the package name not accepted...I update the version code and name from manifest and fix it!

Answer (score 0):

in the android menifest in your new APK change these two lines:

```
android:versionCode="the higher the number here, the newer the apk is to the android market- for ex. 2"
android:versionName="here is your version name- for ex. 1.0.2"
```

after that publish the apk

Answer (score 0):

## Also sign your export version .apk file with the same .keystore file::

Try to publish your new .apk file with manifest included ::#

```
<application
android:versionCode="2.0" //higher number than your previous version(1.0) so 2.0 --> new version >      old version
android:versionName="2.0.0" //these version which would be display at Google Play Store
>  

</application>
```